# When iterating through a very large list and writing to a file each iteration, should the file be opened in the loop or outside the loop?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, performance, file-io

I know the title probably isn't the best way of wording my question, so please feel free to change it if you can come up with something better!

I have a large list of strings (somewhere between 50k-100k) that I would like to iterate through, and within each iteration, get some information about the file, then write the item with its information to a file.

My initial implementation had a second list, and each iteration would append a dict with the item and its information. Then, once the list had been iterated through, the second list (of dicts) would be written to a json file. However, I did not consider the fact that all of this would be stored in memory and due to the size of the list, there was the possibility that it would run out of memory before finishing, and I'd have to restart.

Original implementation:

```
results = []
for f in long_list:
    results.append({"item": f, "otherdata": some_function(f)})
    print(results[len(results)-1])

with open("results.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(results, fp)
```

So my second implementation instead writes to a file (I'm fine if it's not JSON, I can convert it later) every iteration, so running out of memory won't be a problem (unless it will, please correct me if I'm wrong). But with this implementation, I'm not sure if the `with open("file_name.txt", "a") as f` should go in the for loop or outside the for loop.

So here are my questions:

1. Will my script run out of memory or is the list too small for that to happen (32GB of RAM on the computer I'm using)?
2. If running out of memory is not going to be a problem, should I stick with the first implementation or should I still opt for the second implementation (write to file each iteration)?
3. If I should opt for the second implementation, should I put the `with open` inside the loop or outside? What would be more efficient and less likely to cause issues?
4. Is there a better way to do this? Using CSV files instead?

Comment: I don't see any issue keeping the file open for the whole time, reopening it certainly seems wasteful. As alternative to a list, you could use a generator. This is one of the typical use cases for generators.

Comment: Applications use virtual memory, the amount of RAM you have doesn't limit the amount of memory that Python can use.

Comment: @PaulRooney so would it be better to go with the second implementation (writing to a file in each iteration) or is the first implementation (storing it in memory until the end) fine?

Comment: Let's say each `dict` object in `results` requires 500 bytes of memory; `long_list` as a whole will only be ~50MB, which isn't that much.

Comment: @Shea you should try both options and see which one works best for you.